# How do you include ProjectItem when deploying DSL?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dsl-tools

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2, I want to package and deploy my completed DSL along with the generated ProjectItem. I can see everything has been compiled correctly. I have my VSIX file but that does not include the Zipped Project Item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug with Visual Studio Beta 2

I have found a workaround by adding some guids

{82b43b9b-a64c-4715-b499-d71e9ca2bd60};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}

into the csproj and manually editing the vsixmanifest to add

ItemTemplates

I created a folder called ItemTemplates and then added the generated project item Zip into the folder , I then set the Zip as Content and changed the IncludeInVSIX property to 'True'